# ASP MVC type or namespace could not be found for db connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm relatively new to ASP MVC coding. I created an application using MVC 5 and Entity Framework (EF) to return data from a database and allow the user to enter and modify data as well.

The application was working fine until I upgraded from Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web to Visual Studio 2013 Community. I'm not sure what changed but when I try to build my project now, I'm getting the following error in all of my controllers:

*"The type or namespace name 'FVMasterConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"*

The FVMasterConnection is the connection to the database which is specified in my web.config file. What's really odd is that the application runs fine through the server with the code below. However, I can't make any changes unless I do it manually on the server since Visual Studio will no longer build my project without throwing the error above.

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing EF and changing code around but I can't get this error to go away.

I was wondering if anyone has any insight as to why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it? I'm wondering if I'm missing a reference somewhere that I'm just not seeing?

I have included the beginning code for one of my controllers below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PagedList;
using jmcAudit.Models;

namespace jmcAudit.Controllers
{
    public class jmc_auditController : Controller
    {
        private FVMasterConnection db = new FVMasterConnection();
```

The private FVMasterConnection db = new FVMasterConnection(); is where I'm getting the error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF you don't create in instance of your web config connection string name. Instead you should create an instance of the class inheriting `DbContext`.

You can check this article for a tutorial on using EF: [Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: So if I rewrite my code and create an instance of a class inheriting DbContext, I'm assuming that would solve the error then? I'm just wondering why my code worked fine before and let me build and now it's not.

Comment: @MikeN yes. The problem is that you don't have a `FVMasterConnection` class defined in your code at all.